# Create XAML canvas programmatically using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, mvvm

I'm using `Elysium` framework to use the `ApplicationBar` control, and I want to make its `CommandButton` dynamic for my Views. So, I'm binding its `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection<CommandButton>` and each view will create its own actions.

Before using `Elysium` I had this button:

```
<Button>
    <Canvas Width="60" Height="60" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="27.854" Height="31.076" Canvas.Top="14" Fill="White" 
              Data="F1 M 51.5487,37.9814L 56.814,41.0534L 50.3383,48.7636L 50.3383,48.8841L 60.0205,46.9565L 60.0205,53.0403L 50.2777,51.414L 50.2777,51.5344L 56.814,59.0037L 51.4882,62.0757L 47.978,52.7994L 47.8569,52.7994L 44.4072,62.0757L 39.2025,59.0037L 45.6782,51.4742L 45.6177,51.3537L 36.1159,53.0403L 36.1159,46.9565L 45.5571,48.8841L 45.5571,48.7636L 39.2025,41.1137L 44.5888,37.9814L 47.9174,47.3179L 48.0385,47.3179L 51.5487,37.9814 Z M 20,17L 43.25,17L 56,29.75L 56,39L 52,36.75L 52,34L 39,34L 39,21L 24,21L 24,55L 41,55L 37.5,59L 20,59L 20,17 Z M 43,22.25L 43,30L 50.75,30L 43,22.25 Z " Canvas.Left="17.24" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Canvas>
</Button>
```

and this is how I'm creating an action on my View.

```
CommandButtonList.Add(new CommandButton
{
    Header = "new version"
});
```

I would like to know if it's possible to create the `<Canvas>` programmatically? If it's, so how?

**Just remember that I'm using MVVM**

**Edit:**

Each action will have a different `<Canvas>` and `<Path>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're storing a collection of `CommandButton`, which is a `UiElement`, in your ViewModel to bind to then you're already breaking one of the main "rules" of MVVM: no View in the ViewModel. If you want to really go the MVVM route, change your collection to some data type and then handle the setup of the UI controls (`CommandButton`, `Canvas`, etc.) in XAML with `DataTemplates`. If you want to stick with your current direction then you might as well just create and assign the `Canvas` right there with the `CommandButton` creation.

What your collection data items look like all depends on what needs to be set differently on each button. If you think about creating a set of buttons manually, every property that's different across each one should be bound to a field on the data item for that button. Data can be as simple as a collection of strings. This could be used for a different raster image on each button (lots of different options for locations):

```
CommandButtonList = new ObservableCollection<string>
{
    "http://foo.com/image1.jpg",
    @"c:\images\image2.jpg",
    "/ProjectImages/image3.jpg"
};
```

Then your `ItemsControl` that binds to it would set its `ItemTemplate` to something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button>
        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where the binding now uses the strings from the collection. This is obviously a simple example and there's lots of additional variation you can do: more complex data objects with lots of properties, more complex template with lots of bindings, multiple data templates on the same `ItemsControl` by either template `DataType` or a `TemplateSelector`, etc.

Comment: That is a great point, indeed. Could you provide some code to show me how to create this collection of data type to link with DataTemplate? And if I do this, how can I be sure that all my buttons won't have the same image?

Comment: And if I choose to stick with my current durection, how can I create and assing the `Canvas`?

Comment: Example added. The other way, Canvas is just an object and you want to assign it to a property, probably Content or Header, so new CommandButton { Header = new Canvas() };

Comment: John, thanks for you're answer. You really helped me with your example and your sentence "you're breaking the main rule of MVVM", that made me put some effort and write an appropriate code for this situation.